# Возможно ли редактирование сообщения пользователя в TeleBot?

Tags: python-3.x, telegram, бот, telebot

Возможно ли редактировать сообщение пользователя в Telegram с помощью TeleBot? Покажите пожалуйста пример

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет, в телеграмме нет возможности изменять сообщения другого пользователя без наличия его токена. Их можно только удалить, если это беседа и у бота есть права, и переслать